# Showing Images based on database field

Tags: php, mysql

I have an application system, and on my summary page (myaccount) I have the list of pages a user has to fill in. However I want to show an image next to each link (a cross at default) but when a user saves that particular page and the database field 'complete' in changes from 0 to 1, the image should change to my tick image. Meaning that page is complete.
If anyone can help that would be great.
I'm still learning!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question isn't complete and not specifying your problem. I am assuming that you need to know how to do it. In which case, you will probably be doing something like following,

1. As soon as the user saves the page, you will be storing that information in some kind of database, that information will tell you which image to show.
2. When you open the home page, just go to database and check if a record for that page exists in database. If it does then show tick else show cross.

**UPDATE:**

You will run a select query. eg. Your table is PAGE and page name is "page1" (or any other field that identifies the page uniquely.) Your query will be soemthing like,

"SELECT complete From PAGE where Unique_Field = 'unique_page_field'"

And then you would have an if check, check if complete == 1 then show tick else show cross.

If you have a really large collection of pages then instead of hitting database for every page, you can run one single query, such as SELECT complete, Unique_Field From PAGE and for every page, you will just check this collection for given record. So if given page is in the collection then show tick else show cross.

**UPDATE For IF Statement:** 
Assuming you will go for first approach :

1. You ran the query : "SELECT complete From PAGE where Unique_Field = 'unique_page_field'"

and now you have the value in $isComplete variable, here's what you will do in your HTML side code,

```
<img src='<?php if($isComplete) echo "tick.jpg"; else echo "cross.jpg"; ?>' />
```

make sure that your image paths are correct.

Comment: Yes exactly I dont know where to start. Yes so when the field 'complete' changes to 1, as it will do when the page is saved. So how would I check in the database?

Comment: Could you provide more info with the if statement. Thanks so much

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by running just one single query if he has a really large collection of pages. If this unique page field really is unique, it needs to be marked as such in MySQL with a UNIQUE index. That index would get MySQL virtually straight to the record relevant to a query that's only looking up a unique value, even in tables with tens of millions of rows.

Comment: Daan, that still would mean mean a trip to database, 1000 trips for 1000 records. The idea was just to draw attention to other specs like performance consideration, I don't even think this is one of his worries right now :)

Comment: This is the code I'm using but it shows the tick even when complete is 0
`<?php
        $isComplete= mysql_query("SELECT complete From Personal where complete = '1'") ?>
        <img src='<?php if($isComplete) echo "tick.png"; else echo "cross.png"; ?>' />`

Comment: Make it : <img src='<?php if($isComplete == 1) echo "tick.png"; else echo "cross.png"; ?>' />